# Error in Iteration example in A Tour of the Dart Libraries

Tags: dart

### Problem

How can I implement the example of Iteration in A Tour of the Dart Libraries?

I understood that it is a code that must be supplemented, but how do I supplement it?

[A Tour of the Dart Libraries](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/library-tour)

```
class Process {
  // Represents a process...
}

class ProcessIterator implements Iterator<Process> {
  @override
  Process get current => ...
  @override
  bool moveNext() => ...
}

// A mythical class that lets you iterate through all
// processes. Extends a subclass of [Iterable].
class Processes extends IterableBase<Process> {
  @override
  final Iterator<Process> iterator = ProcessIterator();
}

void main() {
  // Iterable objects can be used with for-in.
  for (var process in Processes()) {
    // Do something with the process.
  }
}
```

### Development Environment

- Dart 2
- [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

### Tried → Error

I read and executed the document on my own, but the following error occurred.

```
class ProcessIterator implements Iterator<Process> {
  @override
  Process get current => new Process();
  @override
  bool moveNext() => false;
}
```

-> Error: 'IterableBase' expects 0 type arguments.

Best regards,

Comment: Which version of Dart are you using?

Comment: @Kevin thank you for  the advice. I added the version of Dart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

1) `Process` is not available on the web, so your DartPad example won't work.

2) `IterableBase` is in `dart:collection`. Don't forget to import that.

This code seems to work for me:

```
import 'dart:collection';

class ProcessIterator implements Iterator<int> {
  @override
  int get current => 0;
  @override
  bool moveNext() => false;
}

// A mythical class that lets you iterate through all
// processes. Extends a subclass of [Iterable].
class Processes extends IterableBase<int> {
  @override
  final Iterator<int> iterator = ProcessIterator();
}

main() {
  for (var thing in Processes()) {
    print(thing);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind, it's often MUCH easier to use `sync*` for custom iterators.

```
Iterable<int> _myProcesses() sync* {
  yield 1;
  yield 2;
  yield 3;
}

main() {
  for (var thing in _myProcesses()) {
    print(thing);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to @Kevin 's answer and rewrite the code below.

### Code

```
import 'dart:collection';

class Process {
  var foo = 'foo';
}

class ProcessIterator implements Iterator<Process> {

  int i = 0;

  @override
  Process get current => new Process();
  @override
  bool moveNext() {
    if(i++ < 5) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

// A mythical class that lets you iterate through all
// processes. Extends a subclass of [Iterable].
class Processes extends IterableBase<Process> {
  @override
  final Iterator<Process> iterator = ProcessIterator();
}

void main() {
  // Iterable objects can be used with for-in.
  for (var process in Processes()) {
    print(process.foo);
  }
}
```

### Console

```
foo
foo
foo
foo
foo
```